# Getting public event feed with pictures of the people who commented

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm creating a website which is going to implement an equivalent of a facebook wall.
For each public event, I'm creating a page and getting the feed of each event via the graph api by issuing a post message on /event_id/feed.

Facebook returns the comments/posts of the users in an array and I can retrieve the message of each post along with the user_id who made the post or wrote a message.

The problem is that I'm required to display the picture of the user_id I'm getting through the json object from facebook.

Can I include somehow the users pictures in the json object I'm receiving from facebook?
If not, making a series of facebook api calls (looping through the user ids) seems very unprofessional. Is there any other solution though?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Field Expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) is your friend:

```
EVENT_ID/feed?fields=id,message,from.fields(name,id,picture)
```